# Ruby on Rails hstore query date greater

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hstore

I am trying to query a hstore value called "date_of_birth" that is inside a column named "physical".
The value is a unix time stored as a string.

```
dob = (Time.now - 18.years.ago)
User.where("(physical ? 'date_of_birth')::int > dob")
```

My code looks this.

Any help / advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User.date_of_birth_before(Time.now-18.years)
```

this worked for me.